# How can I read blackslashes from a file correctly?

Tags: python, file-io

The following code:

```
key = open("C:\Scripts\private.ppk",'rb').read()
```

reads the file and assigns its data to the var `key`.

For a reason, backslashes are multiplied in the process. How can I make sure they don't get multiplied?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You ... don't.  They are escaped when they are read in so that they will process properly when they are written out / used.  If you're declaring strings and don't want to double up the back slashes you can use raw strings `r'c:\myfile.txt'`, but that doesn't really apply to the contents of a file you're reading in.

```
>>> s = r'c:\boot.ini'
>>> s
'c:\\boot.ini'
>>> repr(s)
"'c:\\\\boot.ini'"
>>> print s
c:\boot.ini
>>>
```

As you can see, the extra slashes are stored internally, but when you use the value in a print statement (write a file, test for values, etc.) they're evaluated properly.

Comment: Why does this answer have six upvotes? "They are escaped when they are read in" is exactly the opposite of what happens. The extra slashes are added by `repr()`; they are not stored in the string, and therefore don't need to be "evaluated" by `print` when printing normally.

Answer (score 4):

You should read this great blog post on [python and the backslash escape](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-are-escape-characters/) character.

> And under some circumstances, if
>   Python prints information to the
>   console, you will see the two
>   backslashes rather than one. For
>   example, this is part of the
>   difference between the repr() function
>   and the str() function.
>
> myFilename =
>   "c:\newproject\typenames.txt" print
>   repr(myFilename), str(myFilename)
>   produces
>
> 'c:\newproject\typenames.txt'
>   c:\newproject\typenames.txt

Answer (score 0):

Backslashes are represented as escaped. You'll see two backslashes for each real one existing on the file, but that is normal behaviour.

The reason is that the backslash is used in order to create codes that represent characters that cannot be easily represented, such as new line '\n' or tab '\t'.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to put single backslashes in a string? Strings with backslashes require and escape character, in this case "\". It will print to the screen with a single slash

Answer (score 0):

In fact there is a solution - using `eval`, as long as the file content can be wrapped into quotes of some kind. Following worked for me (PATH contains some script that executes Matlab):

```py
MATLAB_EXE = "C:\Program Files (x86)\MATLAB\R2012b\bin\matlab.exe"
content = open(PATH).read()
MATLAB_EXE in content  # False
content = eval(f'r"""{content}"""')
MATLAB_EXE in content  # True
```

This works by evaluating the content as python string literal, making double escapes transform into single ones. Raw string is used to prevent escapes forming special characters.